# Difference between 16:9 and 16:10 aspect ratio based on laptop's display size

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-display, 4k-resolution, aspect-ratio

I know that the 16:10 aspect ratio gives more vertical area than the 16:9 aspect ratio.

I'm planning on buying a new laptop with a 4K UHD display, and my question is if a 15.6 inch display with an aspect ratio of 16:9 would give more vertical area than a 13.1 inch display that makes use of 16:10 aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2):

Using an
[online trigonometric calculator](http://cossincalc.com/),
I get these values for a triangle:

```
Hypotenuse of 15.6, right angle with 16:9 ratio : height is 7.65 inch
Hypotenuse of 13, right angle with 16:10 ratio : height is 6.89 inch
```

So the answer is that a 15.6 inch screen would be
larger on all dimensions than a 13 inch.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer would be Yes? Because `7.65` inch is more than `6.89` inch?

Comment: I may be answering the wrong question. I gave the answer a safer wording.

Comment: Keep in mind that actual amount of content that will fit on screen depends only on resolution, ie. number of pixels (and scaling settings). It can be smaller, though, if physical pixels are smaller.